# Running ssh in c++ with popen function or using non-compiled library

Tags: c++, linux, ssh

I want to run some script on remote device using ssh, but I don't want to use a library. I want to run popen function and run ssh.

```
FILE *f = popen( "ssh -t -t root@192.168.1.2", "r" );

if(f)
{
    fprintf(f, "/opt/somescript.sh\n");
    pclose(f);
}
```

I can see that the connection established and closed on the terminal, when I run this code. But the script doesn't really run on the remote machine.

Don't want to use a library means, compiled library. Because this code will run different platforms and I cannot compile the library for every platform. If I can use pure c++ code, it will be OK. I downloaded libssh source codes but it's so compicated and I didn't understand how to use it without compiling.

Comment: Outch! This lacks even the most basic basics. Either rewrite [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) or add the name of the script to the command line of ssh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input and output are wrong. You open the ssh with "r", which means you're interested in the script output, but then you try to `fprintf` into it, which makes no sense.

Try to replace the popen with:
`FILE *f = popen( "ssh -t -t root@192.168.1.2 /opt/somescript.sh", "r" );`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wrote the code wrong here but I already tested with "w".

Comment: @mehmetfa also note that I put the script name to run on the ssh command line.

Answer (score 0):

what is the output of this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    FILE * fp = popen( "ssh -t -t root@192.168.1.2", "r" );
    if ( !fp ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not execute command \n" );
        return 1;
    }
    const int BUFSIZE = 1000;
    char buff[ BUFSIZE ];
    while( fgets( buf, sizeof( buff ),  fp ) ) {
        fprintf( stdout, "%s", buff  );
    }
    pclose( fp );
    fp=NULL;
    return 0;
}
```